# Calling Powershell script from ASP.NET (C#), but not wait for results

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I have a powershell script that I want to call from a web page.  I have the c# code in and it works, but the script is ultimately doing some sql tasks that aren't speedy in return.  It doesn't have any results that I want to display to the web page, so I can't seem to get the web page to fire the script and then move on.  It keeps stating "waiting for server..." in the bottom of my browser even though there isn't anything to return.  Eventually the page times out.

I've tried to use the InvokeAsync() option, but it's still giving me the same results.  Would using Process.Start() have any better luck in calling a Powershell script and then moving on?
Thanks,
Greg

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
string cmdArg = scriptfile + " " + TextBox4.Text + " " + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
//Collection<PSObject> psresults;
using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
{
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmdArg);
    //psresults = pipeline.Invoke();
    pipeline.InvokeAsync(); // InvokeAsync calls it as a background process so it won't make the web page timeout.
}

runspace.Close();
```

Comment: any final solution about it and full source code?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Runspace pipeline asynchronously, but you opened your Runspace synchronously

Try to use :

```
runspace.OpenAsync();
```

Hope that helped :)

Comment: When I change my Open() to OpenAsync(), I get a runtime error that the Runspace is not in an Open stating, when I debug, the state is in "Opening" and never gets to "Open".

Comment: One workaround would then be to move all this logic into a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be putting the runspace in a using clause - it will try to dispose it immediately after the invokeasync call, and block. You should instead be disposing the runspace in a callback.

Comment: I took the code out of the using block, but it didn't change anything. The web page still waits for a response and eventually times out.